# how to assign height to div using variable?

Tags: jquery

how to assign height to div using variable? I know we can assign height with variable by putting variable inside of height method, but why its not taking height with assign operator.?
here is the example below I was trying.

```
        $('.last-input input').focus(function(){
        console.log('focus');
        var keyboardHeight = $('.keyboard-div').height();
        var formrowH = $('.formrow').height();
        console.log('keyboardHeight', keyboardHeight);            
        console.log('formrow height', $('.formrow').height());
      //$('.formrow').height(formrowH)
        $('.formrow').height() = formrowH;
      });
```

Comment: `$('.formrow').height(formrowH)` which you commented. Also go through official docs http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2

Comment: And you can't see any change cause you assign to `.formrow` height his current height..

Answer (score 1):

That is because

```
$('.formrow').height()
```

returns a value and not "the variable that determines the height"

As @Satpal pointed out, use

```
$('.formrow').height(formrowH)
```

to set the height of `.formrow` to the value stored in `formrowH`